# Counter Discord bot reports a "IndentationError"

Tags: python, discord

Here is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global counter
    if message.author == client.user:
        counter += 1


    if message.content.startswith('Count'):
    await message.channel.send('Ya', counter)
```

and it take error:

```
 C:\>Users\nasty\Desktop\discord\text.py
  File "C:\Users\nasty\Desktop\discord\text.py", line 13
    global counter
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Intent the await thingy one tab or 4 spaces to the right if it is supposed to be part of the if-block

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is fix your indentation.

Change this

```
if message.content.startswith('Count'):
await message.channel.send('Ya', counter)
```

Into this

```
if message.content.startswith('Count'):
    await message.channel.send('Ya', counter)
```

Comment: Trivial solutions like this are probably worth just adding as a comment.

Comment: Yeah but at the time I didn't have enough reputation to comment